# Menu Buttons Layout

Tags: android, layout, menu, icons

[image]

I want to create a menu with 6 buttons that is suppose to be in this layout. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You should show what you have tried in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you that exact layout (I used `ImageButton`s in this layout)

I added the scroll view so that the menu will scroll on very small screens. You can remove that if you want.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:weightSum="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/id1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/id2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/id3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/id4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/id5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/id6"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Or you can just use a `TableLayout`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<TableLayout> ... </TableLayout>`

example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/